# vim regex : how to replace enclosing backticks with tags

Tags: regex, search, vim, replace

I have this document in *Markdown* in which i constantly reference keys to be pressed(at the time i wasn't aware of the `<kbd>` tags!) and have enclosed them in backticks instead. So for example I have a lot of text like `Shift` and `Shift + A`,etc... and I would like to convert them to `<kbd>Shift<\kbd>` or `<kbd>Shift + A<\kbd>` instead, using the Vim search and replace options.

Right now, the only way that I think of doing this is by replacing the opening backtick with a `<kbd>` and then **separately** replacing the closing backtick with a `<\kbd>`. But I was wondering if this could be done in a **single search** and replace command using capture groups or something?

Comment: ```echo '`Shift`' | sed 's/`\([^`][^`]*\)`/<kbd>\1<\\kbd>/g'```
```<kbd>Shift<\kbd>```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the substitution command:

```
%s/`\([^`]\+\)`/<kbd>\1<\/kbd>/g
```

This captures runs between backticks and replaces the inner text with wrapped `<kbd>` tags.

By the way, `</kbd>` is the proper HTML closing tag, so I assume you want that instead of `<\kbd>`.